# mysql vs mariadb query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, mariadb-10.6

Hope i don't make any mistakes posting here :)

Hi everyone,

i'm using the following query on mysql and works perfect. But when i use the same query (same database) on a mariadb i'm getting wrong values.

I've tried to search but didn't find any solution.
checked the variables with phpmyadmin etc.. innodb values...

a hint in the right direction would be great.

mariadb-version:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

mysql-version:
mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Best regards
Ralph

```
With allresults As (
        Select
            *
        From
            testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker
    )
Select
    final.crmid As crmid,
    final.changedon As Datum,
    final.fieldname As AbschlussgrundFeld,
    final.prevalue As AbschlussgrundAlt,
    final.postvalue As Abschlussgrund,
    testtesttest.vtiger_account.projektnameacc As Projektname,
    testtesttest.vtiger_account.datenquelleacc As Quelle
From
    (
        Select
            Concat(Date(testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker.changedon), " 23:59:59") As changedon,
            testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity.deleted,
            allresults.crmid,
            allresults.changedon As changedon1,
            allresults.fieldname,
            allresults.prevalue,
            allresults.postvalue
        From
            testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker Inner Join
            testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity On testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity.crmid = testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker.crmid Left Join
            allresults On allresults.changedon <= testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker.changedon
        where testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0
        Group By
            allresults.crmid,
            testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker.changedon
        Order By
            testtesttest.abschlussgrundtracker.changedon Desc,
            changedon1 Desc
    ) As final Inner Join
    testtesttest.vtiger_account On testtesttest.vtiger_account.accountid = final.crmid Inner Join
    testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity On testtesttest.vtiger_account.accountid = testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity.crmid
where testtesttest.vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0
Group By
    final.crmid,
    final.changedon,
    Projektname,
    Quelle
Order By
    Datum
```

my solution:

```
With
    tester As (
        Select
            *
        From
            (
                Select Distinct
                    *
                From
                    (
                        Select
                            Concat(abschlussgrundtracker.crmid, Left(abschlussgrundtracker.changedon, 10)) As crmiddate,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.whodid,
                            Left(abschlussgrundtracker.changedon, 10) As testerdate,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.crmid,
                            Date_Format(abschlussgrundtracker.changedon, "%Y-%m-%d %T") As datim,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.changedon,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.fieldname,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.prevalue,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.postvalue as Abschlussgrund,
                            vtiger_account.accountname,
                            vtiger_account.accountid,
                            vtiger_account.datenquelleacc AS Quelle,
                            vtiger_account.projektnameacc AS Projectname
                        From
                            abschlussgrundtracker Inner join
                            vtiger_account On vtiger_account.accountid = abschlussgrundtracker.crmid Inner Join
                            vtiger_accountscf On vtiger_accountscf.accountid = vtiger_account.accountid
                                Inner Join vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_account.accountid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid Inner Join
                            vtiger_users On vtiger_users.id = abschlussgrundtracker.whodid
                        Group By
                            abschlussgrundtracker.crmid,
                            abschlussgrundtracker.changedon
                        Having
                            abschlussgrundtracker.changedon = Max(abschlussgrundtracker.changedon) And
                            abschlussgrundtracker.crmid
                    ) As test
                Order By
                    test.datim Desc
            ) As test2
    ),
alldates as (
Select distinct
        concat(left(abschlussgrundtracker.changedon,10)," 23:59:59") as Datum
From
        abschlussgrundtracker
group by
        abschlussgrundtracker.crmid,abschlussgrundtracker.changedon
),
getunique as (
Select
    *
From
    tester
group by tester.crmiddate
order by tester.datim DESC
)

select Datum,crmid,whodid,Abschlussgrund,Quelle,Projectname
from  
(
select *
from
      alldates full join
      getunique
where Datum >= datim
order by Datum
) as bla
group by bla.Datum,bla.crmid
```

Comment: You might want to add what results you get and what you expect, along with some sample data. Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB are effectively different products. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and these two products have been diverging gradually since then. In particular, both of them have implemented support for CTE queries since they diverged, so they are bound to have differences, just as they both potentially would get different results from the implementations in other brands of database like PostgreSQL, Microsoft, Oracle, etc.

Comment: What is both systems' `sql_mode`?

Comment: SQL_mode are both the same... i additionally checked the flags and adjusted them... but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect - its GROUP BY (both) are incomplete. This is the source of the difference - the values for some output columns are indefinite. And the fact that "the following query on mysql and works perfect" simply claims that you're lucky (but you may obtain the output which is not correct for you at any time).

Fix this. Either expand grouping expression or add aggregate functions into the output expression.

---

PS. Your current CTE `allresults` is obviously excess - remove it and use its source table instead of this CTE in your query.

PPS. Convert your `final` subquery to CTE - this will make your query more readable.